# Accessing SQLite Database in R

Tags: database, r, sqlite

I want to access and manipulate a large data set in R. Since it's a large CSV file (~ 0.5 GB), I plan to import it
to SQLite and then access it from R. I know the `sqldf` and `RSQLite` packages can do this but I went 
over their manuals and they are not helpful. Being a newbie to SQL doesn't help either.

I want to know do I have to set the R directory to SQLite's and then go from there? How do I read in the database in R then?
Heck, if you know how to access the DB from R without using SQL, please tell me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It really is rather easy -- the path and filename to the sqlite db file is passed as the 'database' parameter.  Here is CRANberries does:

```
databasefile <- "/home/edd/cranberries/cranberries.sqlite"

## ...

## main worker function
dailyUpdate <- function() {
    stopifnot(all.equal(system("fping cran.r-project.org", intern=TRUE), 
                        "cran.r-project.org is alive"))
    setwd("/home/edd/cranberries")
    dbcon <- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = databasefile)
    repos <- dbGetQuery(dbcon, 
                        paste("select max(id) as id, desc, url ",
                              "from repos where desc!='omegahat' group by desc")
    # ...
```

That's really all there is.  Of course, there are other queries later on...

You easily test all SQL queries in the sqlite client before trying from R, or trying directly from R.

***Edit:*** As the above was apparently too terse, here is an example straight from the documentation:

```
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")         ## in-memory, replace with file
data(USArrests)
dbWriteTable(con, "arrests", USArrests)

res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * from arrests")
data <- fetch(res, n = 2)
data

dbClearResult(res)
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from arrests limit 3")
```

Comment: Okay. First I have to import the CSV files into SQLite, right? Then the CSV file becomes a .sqlite file. Then how does R know where to read in the .sqlite file? If you are giving a solution, then at least write comments to your code rather than dump it on other people. Thank you.

Comment: You have to provide a sqlite db, how to create those is covered in the sqlite docs (which are rather decent). See how the variable `databasefile` is used above--that is all, as I wrote.

Comment: @GTyler: LOL! If you are asking for free help, then at least show _some_ appreciation rather than criticizing them for not providing the best possible answer. Thank you. ;-)