# Accessing large spreadsheets written from R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, data.table, fwrite

I am using the following R script to write the data. table into the excel file in my set directory. However, the size of the file is in GB's as the total rows are 50 million+. Hence upon opening the file, I just see a blank grey screen and nothing else.

How can I see the contents in the file?

The first line is just for illustration purpose.

```
 Final1 <- rep(iris, times = 1000000)
 fwrite(Final1,"data2.csv")
```

[image: Excel_Capture]

Comment: If you are dealing with datasets on the order of GB may I suggest that you consider using a relational database instead of Excel?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks a lot for replying, If I got you write, do you suggest importing the excel file in an RDBMS like sap hana?

Comment: What is the intended use of this file?  Excel can only hold just over a million rows (in a single sheet)

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for replying, See the file basically is a report which will have a data frame computed in R which will go in millions, kindly suggest a good approach as I need to have all the data in one place.

Comment: One one place *to do what*?

Comment: If you need a report with millions of rows why not to store it in csv?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Lets say I am comparing 10K name entries with 10K entries and giving a similarity score. This text analyses task happens in R and then I need to display the report. So either I can download as a csv, else some other wise approach that you can suggest?

Comment: @PoGibas, thanks for the reply, I am writing the file in excel and storing as a csv. But the records are around 6 million +.So not able to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that this is part of the report. I would be willing to bet good money that whoever will be reading this report will not check all or most of the values by hand. In which case, you don't need a format that is easily browsable, e.g. `xlsx` or even `csv`. If this indeed is the case, you might want to try a (relational) database. If you do not have anything centralized, you might want to give SQLite a try. You save everything into one file which acts as a database. There are packages that handle this interaction in R. You can try with [`sqldf`](http://www.r-chart.com/2010/07/make-r-speak-sql-with-sqldf.html) or [`RSQLite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845639/accessing-sqlite-database-in-r).